# Wordpress - wpml different domains - behind reverse proxy

Tags: wordpress, apache, reverse-proxy, wpml

### Situation

My client has a webshop in 2 languages:
 - my-website.be (Dutch + French)
 - my-website.nl (Dutch)

I have to remake the /blog for these 3 languages using Wordpress.
I have no access to the main website and server, so this has to be done with reverse proxy.

Ideally this will look like this:
 - my-website.**be/nl-be**/blog/%postname%/
 - my-website.**be/fr-be**/blog/%postname%/
 - my-website.**nl**/blog/%postname%/

We use WPML(pro) for translation on the website
I have to proof this is possible

### The problem

I'm trying to proof this is possible with wpml + reverse proxy on my local machine using MampPro for Windows. (As I do not have real/live servers/domains available to test this) And this is not working correctly whatever I try.

### The local test setup

- Made 2 local servers for reverse proxy:

  - my-site.local**be**
  - my-site.local**nl**
- Made 1 local server for the blog: **my-site.test**
- Set the .htaccess files in the 2 proxy domains to reverse proxy this:

my-site.local**be**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteRule ^nl-be/blog/(.*)$ http://my-site.test/$1 [P]  
    RewriteRule ^fr-be/blog/(.*)$ http://my-site.test/$1 [P]  
</IfModule>
```

my-site.local**nl**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://my-site.test/$1 [P]  
</IfModule>
```

- Setup 3 languages in WPML (nl-be, fr-be, nl-nl)
- Set the Wordpress site url to the default http://my-site.test

==> with this setup both reverse proxy domain just show the default homepage and/or subpages. There's no way to access the other languages.

### What we've tried

- Changing Wordpress wp_home and wp_siteurl to:
  /nl-be/blog (as nl-be is set as the default language in wpml)
- Setting up wpml as "different domain for each language", but that places /nl-be/ hardcoded after each of those different domains.
  (with wp_home and wp_siteurl set as my-site.test)
- Fiddling with proxypass settings in .htaccess (probably wrong)
- Changing the wpml language domains hardcoded in database
- Overwriting the server_name variable in functions.php as follows:

  ```
  $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
  ```
- Combinations and variations off all above.

### Results

- Mostly error 500
- A broken .htaccess when saving permalinks
- To much internal redirections
- Links looking like my-site.testbe/**nl-be**/blog/**nl-be**/*
- Styling and scripts loading from wrong domain
- Combinations of all above

### I would like to know

- **if this setup is even possible** (local or on real linux servers)
- if the mistake is in my reverse proxy / htaccess part
- if the mistake is in configuring wordpress and wpml
- any information that can help me solving this.

Thanks a lot,
a developer in distress